# How to create a company specific parent dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

How to create a company specific parent dependency file which can be used across company specific gradle initiated projects

Sample libraries which I want to share across projects

```
dependencies {
    // logging
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'log4j-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.30'

    // elasticsearch
    implementation group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '7.13.2'
    implementation group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '7.13.2'
}
```

Comment: creating a empty poject with `gradle init` and then adding the dependencies you need , then creating a fatJar with all these dependencies then publishing the fatJar to artifactory should make this work , i did not post an answer because there is a lot of details , and am not sure this is exactly what you need to do .

Comment: I am actually looking for the equivalent of the maven parent pom.xml implementation, something similar to https://github.com/jboss/jboss-parent-pom. I don't want to generate a fatJar just for this purpose

Comment: i don't know..., but (e.g.) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/build.gradle is a great/prod/open-source example for a (big) modular gradle project (as all of spring-projects)

Comment: is a gradle "platform" what you're looking for? https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:using-platform-to-control-transitive-deps

Comment: @Joe does the platform concept work for gradle plugins section as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is the goal of the parent POM? If it's only for the consolidation dependency versions, you can use a [version catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html).
A version catalog is a list of dependencies, represented as dependency coordinates, that a user can pick from when declaring dependencies in a build script.

`settings.gradle`

```
enableFeaturePreview('VERSION_CATALOGS')
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            // logging
            alias('slf4j-api').to('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30')
            alias('log4j-over-slf4j').to('org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.30')

            // elasticsearch
            alias('elasticsearch').to('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.13.2')
            alias('elasticsearch-client').to('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.13.2')
            alias('elasticsearch-rest').to('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.13.2')
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // logging
    implementation libs.slf4j.api
    implementation libs.log4j.over.slf4j

    // elasticsearch
    implementation libs.elasticsearch
    implementation libs.elasticsearch.client
    implementation libs.elasticsearch.rest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate Gradle project which maintains [a *version catalog*](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:version-catalog) for the whole company. That project then publishes the version catalog to a company-specific repository (like Artifactory). Other company projects can then fetch and use the published version catalog.

Version catalogs can not only be used in normal project dependency declarations but also [in plugin dependency declarations](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/platforms.html#sec:plugins).

**Important note:** as of this writing, this central declaration of dependencies feature is still incubating (in the latest Gradle version 7.3.2). See also the warning on [this Gradle docs section](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies).

### Sample Projects

Below are two complete sample projects:

- `mycompany-catalog` is the project that maintains and publishes the version catalog.
- `mycompany-app` is some application that uses the published version catalog.

I’ve tested this setup with Gradle 7.3.2. For simplicity and self-containedness, I use a local Maven repository.

#### `mycompany-catalog` Project

You can publish the version catalog as follows:
`./gradlew publish`

See also the Gradle docs on:

- [the `version-catalog` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/platforms.html#sec:version-catalog-plugin)
- [how to declare a version catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:version-catalog-declaration)

##### `settings.gradle`

```groovy
enableFeaturePreview('VERSION_CATALOGS')

rootProject.name = 'mycompany-catalog'
```

##### `build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'version-catalog'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

// the coordinates of the published catalog
group = 'com.mycompany'
version = 0.42

catalog {
    versionCatalog {
        // logging
        alias('slf4j-api').to('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30')
        alias('log4j-over-slf4j').to('org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.30')

        // elasticsearch
        alias('elasticsearch').to('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.13.2')
        alias('elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client').to(
            'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.13.2')
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.versionCatalog
        }
    }
    repositories {
        // the company-internal repo to which we publish the version catalog
        maven {
            url = 'file:///tmp/mycompany-repo'
        }
    }
}
```

#### `mycompany-app` Project

You can check that this works as expected using something like:
`./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath`

See also the Gradle docs on [importing a published catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/platforms.html#sec:importing-published-catalog).

##### `settings.gradle`

```groovy
enableFeaturePreview('VERSION_CATALOGS')

rootProject.name = 'mycompany-app'

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        // the same company-internal repo (to which we published the version
        // catalog in the other project)
        maven {
            url = 'file:///tmp/mycompany-repo'
        }
        // a repository from which the external dependencies are fetched
        mavenCentral()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            // our published catalog
            from('com.mycompany:mycompany-catalog:0.42')
        }
    }
}
```

##### `build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    // logging
    implementation(libs.slf4j.api)
    implementation(libs.log4j.over.slf4j)

    // elasticsearch
    implementation(libs.elasticsearch)
    implementation(libs.elasticsearch.rest.high.level.client)
}

// …
```